# How to programmatically get cellID from IPAQ pocket PC

Tags: windows-mobile, mobile, pocketpc, cellid

I'm trying to get CellID and Lac on HP IPAQ 614c. 
I've tried using RIL interface with no luck RIL_GetCellTowerInfo returns E_NOTIMPL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If RIL isn't providing the information then I think you are out of luck. I believe that RIL is the lowest level that WM uses to talk to the Radio Hardware.

You will have it try to look for a HP supplied library to get the information or you have to figure out how to talk to the Radio Hardware directly.

Comment: I've tried to make use of ipaqutil.dll, supplied with firmware, still no luck. Library has set of function for querying GSM radio, but nothing about CellId.

I have tried to open com port on built in GSM modem, on comm port COM2, but that did not worked out, port can be opened, but does not answer to AT commands. (AT+CREG=2) 

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Cell ID (LAC + CID) as a notification using this Library:

http://teksoftco.com/index.php?section=press&cat=2009#090611

It comes with C#, C++ and VB samples.

Here's how a simple app that reads the CellID looks like:

Comment: I have tried it it doesn't work, probably because it's based on RIL (as name suggests ?). Problem that I am facing on IPAQ is that RIL interface is not implemented.